# How do I change a class to a template class?

Tags: c++

I need to change the first line to :  `template <class T> class Node{`

```
class Node {
private:
  double data;
  Node* next;
public:
  Node(double);
  virtual ~Node(); //for later use of polymorphismi, review the topic again

  friend class Stack; // allows dStack for private member access
};

Node::Node(double data) {
  this->data = data;
  next = 0;
}

Node::~Node() {
}
```

but i am unsure of all the internal work i need to change. Do i just need to change the private data member and the public Node function?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want to store a `T` instead of a `double`? (hint: this leads to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something along the lines of the following:

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T data;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node(const T& d);
    virtual ~Node();
    // ... etc
};
```

Note that you will either need to implement the template class inline, in the same file, or include the implementation at the bottom of the header file.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you change your class so that it can be used for other types except `double`, for example `int`, `float` etc in the same way. If we think of it in more abstractly, you need to use the class for objects of type `T`, where `T` can be any of the types mentioned above (or even more).
So, in general, you need to put `template <class T>` (Setting it as a template class) before your class and replace `double` with `T` type.

Answer (score 0):

for class declaration:

```
template<typename T>
class Node
```

for class functions implementation:

```
 template<typename T>
 Node<T>::Node()
```

Comment: You cannot split template classes into 2 files unless you include the implementation file at the end of the header file.

Comment: I think you mean template specialization.  Explicit instantiation creates an object without actually using it (still requires the implementation to exist).  Specialization can work, but then you cannot use the template class for anything but what you have specialized.